# Sql to Odata url conversion

Tags: odata

Hi am trying to find out how to write an odata url with a join in it.
I have found this (https://www.progress.com/blogs/rest-api-industry-debate-odata-vs-graphql-vs-ords ) which says that joins are possible but all my search results are coming up with are using linq and i would like to use direct URL.

For this example can we assume ill be connecting to localhost:12344.

here is the sql that i would like to be converted into a url.
`Select * from table1 as T1
join table1 as T2 on T1.table2Id = T2.Id
where T2.ColumnIndifferent = 1`

Thank you in advance for your assistance.